# NativeScript ng2 two way binding doesn`t work on TextField

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-forms, angular2-nativescript

im making a mobile app. In my login form i have 2 TextFields

```html
<TextField hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" [(ngModel)]="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
<TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="password"></TextField>
 <Label [text]="email"></Label>
```

in component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import * as Toast from 'nativescript-toast';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sign-in',
    templateUrl: "template.html"
})
export class SignInPage implements OnInit {
    email: string ="example";
    password: string;
    constructor(private router: Router, page: Page) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
    ngOnInit() {

        var loginParams = { user: { email: this.email }, password: this.password };

        console.dump(loginParams);
    }
}
```

Label is showing "example" but textField does not. Change value of textField doesnt change value in component logic. 
Any Idea?

ps. I already imported NativescriptFormsModule in my @ngModule

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you import NativescriptFormsModule on the module that declare SignInPage Component not only in AppModule.

Comment: i imported this module in my component still doesnt work :(

Comment: i dont understant You at fiirst time. I do what Yoy say and its work! thanks mate !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put it in a shared module if you are using it in many places in your project, for instance:

```
// shared.module.ts

    .....
    import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            .....
            NativeScriptFormsModule,
            .....
        ],
        declarations: [
            .....
        ],
        exports: [
            .....
            NativeScriptFormsModule,
            .....
        ]
    })
    export class SharedModule { }

// signon.module.ts

    .....
    import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";
```

Answer (score 0):

to enable two-way data binding in nativescript you will have to import **NativeScriptFormsModule** in the module. It is just like **FormsModule** which we use angular to enable two-way data binding.

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule
  ]
})
```